# Skyrim Good Intentions / Revealing the Unseen Quest Glitch?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm stuck in the College of Winterhold questline because of a glitch between the quests "Good Intentions" and "Revealing the Unseen." After talking to the Augur of Dunlain, I return to the Archmage Savos Aren to finish the quest, and he gives me the Mage's Circlet and finishes "Good Intentions." The problem is, the next quest "Revealing the Unseen" doesn't start. He talks about Mirabelle Irvine and tells me to go talk to her, but since the quest hasn't been started, she doesn't have anything to say about the Staff of Magnus. I've tried reloading from before the quest many times and finishing it but still the same result. I've also tried doing other quests and coming back to try and finish it later, but still the next quest doesn't start. I'm on the PS3.

Anyone have a way of fixing this bug/glitch? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is starting to sound like a [very](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39067/1980) buggy [quest](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35633/1980)!

Answer (score 4):

According to UESP wiki (and my boyfriend had the same problem with his), if for some reason you accidentally exit out of the conversation with Mirabelle before you talk about the Staff of Magnus, you will be unable to ever have that option again. However, there was supposedly an "unofficial patch" that fixed this.

I'm not sure if these circumstances were the same as yours, but, nevertheless, here's the link and I hope it helps!:

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Revealing_the_Unseen